# Difference between downloading a web file directly & indirectly

Tags: asp.net, download, httpresponse, swfobject

On my web server I have a video file named `03.mp4`.
I have a page (videoserver.aspx) to serve that file using below code

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=video.mp4");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("03.mp4"));
Response.End();
```

Whats the difference between these 2 calls?
1: `http://localhost/media/03.mp4`
2: `http://localhost/media/videoserver.aspx?q=03`

When I point to those URLs directly in my browser, it prompts me a Save dialog in both the cases.
I have another web page that has a SWFObject. It consumes a video as input. Ok. When I feed it URL 1, it loads the video.
When I feed it URL 2, it doesn't load the video.

Why this difference? I prefer URL 2 as you can dynamically change the videos you are serving to consumers based on the query-string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hence it proves I am a newbie to SWFObject.
The SWFObject I was referring to was dished out by Camtasia and it accepts a mp4 file thru FLashVars.
The question is "why did it not accept URL 2 while it accepted URL 1?". To which the answer is, URL 2 was not ending with `.mp4`.
And solution to my problem then was, create a handler that would accept `*/media/*.mp4` path and return the appropriate file's content, which in my case is fetched from DB.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of video players, including the new HTML5 `<video>` element, require support for so-called byte range requests using the HTTP [`Range`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header. This is normally already built in a bit self-respected HTTP server. Basically, to inform the client that the requested URL supports byte range requests, the server is supposed to return [`Accept-Ranges: bytes`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5) on the response and to be able to process all incoming `Range` requests by serving exactly the requested byte ranges back to the response as per the specification (see the first link on the `Range` header for detail).

So if you choose to take the HTTP response handling fully in your own hands instead of letting the HTTP server do the job it is designed for, you have to take this carefully into account.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand how you meant to answer my question. I tried using the `Accept-Ranges: bytes` http header but its not working.

Comment: That alone is not enough :) Did you read the links in my answer? Click the link behind `Range` in my answer. You need to write a whole bunch of code as well to properly intercept on incoming `Range` requests. You need to extract the requested byte range from that header, validate the `If-Range`, retrieve exactly the requested byte range from disk and write it to the response along a set of proper headers. There are several examples available on Google. Try keywords "asp.net range requests" or so. For example, this first hit: http://tpeczek.blogspot.com/2011/10/range-requests-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: For the case that you're more familiar with Java, you may perhaps find my old blog article more helpful, check the "Resume downloads" part: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html

Comment: @BaluC, can you clarify how exactly would Range Request solve my problem? My SWFObject wants a video as input. URL 1 and URL 2 both are serving videos, with some minor variation that I dont understand. How do you think Range Request fits the bill?

Comment: Because they require range requests (which has a lot of benefits as to buffering, multiple connections and so on). You've clearly the evidence yourself. You are not supporting range requests in your code at all, but your webserver did.

Comment: Thanks for your time BalusC. How would you know my SWFObject requires range requests? Its able to pick the file as is. Why problem with file served thru web page?